# php gd, use two image, bad quality

Tags: php, gd

i change image size and put on others, but image quality very poor, why?
(When i save image I set 100 quality)

```
$src = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$src2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_url);
imagecopyresampled($src, $src2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $new_img_size['org_w'], $new_img_size['org_h']);

$bg_size = 600;
$img_center_w = ($bg_size / 2) - ($new_width / 2);
$img_center_h = ($bg_size / 2) - ($new_height / 2);

$dst = imagecreate($bg_size, $bg_size );
$bg = imagecolorallocate($dst, 225, 255, 255);

imagecopy($dst, $src, $img_center_w, $img_center_h, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height);

imagejpeg($dst, 'test_img.jpg', 100);
```

Comment: This looks fine - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533639/image-resize-issue-in-php-gd-creates-ugly-resized-images .  But why don't you do the two steps in one?  That way, you won't resample twice.

Comment: In what way is the image quality poor?

Comment: Borealid>Thanks for link, but in that link i don't find any good ideas for me. Maybe you can more  details.

Comment: What makes you think the quality is bad?

Comment: Mark >I will compare with the original image

Answer (score 0):

```
$dst = imagecreate($bg_size, $bg_size );
```

I guess that's the problem. You should use `imagecreatetruecolor` as above.